# Interprocess communication using named pipes

Tags: c, operating-system

I am trying to write a simple program that passes a value from a process to another without having father-child properties using named pipes.Code i've writen:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>




int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   int fd,i,j;

    int * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    pid_t c=fork();
    if(c==0){
    i=10;
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, &i, sizeof(i));
    printf("my pid is %d \n",getpid());
    }
    if(c>0){
    pid_t c2=fork();
    if(c2==0){
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, &j, sizeof(j));
    printf("passes value is %d",j);
    }
wait(0);
    }



}
```

I want the first child to write 10 to the pipe and the second to read from the file and print so i can know it works.This code gives me multiple errors though that i can't seen to understand.Any ideas?

Errors i get:

```
In function ‘main’:|
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mkfifo’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘open’; did you mean ‘popen’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
]main.c|27|note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
error:'O_WRONLY' undeclared(first use in this function)
error:'O_RDONLY' undeclared(first use in this function)
```

Comment: Which errors do you get? Please attach them to your post.

Comment: _This code gives me multiple errors ?_  Please post those error messages in question itself by editing it. Always check the return value of `open()`. Also do `perror` on `mkfifo` to know whether it able to create FIFO or not

Comment: See the man page of the implicitly declared functions, e.g. `man open` and add the missing `#include` directives. The warning about incompatible types is about `myfifo`. It must be `char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";` (not `int *`) Check the return value of all functions and print the corresponding error if something fails, e.g. `fd = open(...); if(fd < 0) { perror("open"); exit(1); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not including the proper headers.

For [`mkfifo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkfifo.html) you need `sys/stat.h`:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <sys/stat.h>
>
> int mkfifo(const char *path, mode_t mode);
> ```

and for [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) you need `sys/stat.h` and `fcntl.h`:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> [#include <sys/stat.h>
> #include <fcntl.h>
>
> int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
> ```

You also need to actually check the return values when you call those functions - the can and do fail.

Comment: ...and `int * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";` is wrong. It must be `char *`.

Comment: @Bodo Thanks.  I missed **that** one.